# Unable to reduce android app size from 3.9 MB to about 2 MB in Xamarin Studio

Tags: android, xamarin, filesize, xamarin-studio

My project contains only a single `Webview`.

I have selected `Link all assemblies` in Linker tab. I have also selected `Enable Progard` in General tab.

According to the Xamarin forums and many site links that I went through enabling the above two would curb my apk size to 2.9 MB but even after building in the release mode when I publish my app the size remains 3.9 MB. I am using Starter/Free edition of the Xamarin Studio to build my app.

Can anyone suggest if I must do anything more to reduce the app size ?

Comment: Do you build for multiple ABIs?

Comment: @tequilaslammer armeabi-v7a only

Comment: Ok. Multiple ABIs could let to a bigger app size. But in that case there is no reason. I am interested in what other might suggest.

Comment: This is a pretty good resource regarding optimizing Android APK size: http://motzcod.es/post/112072508362/how-to-keep-your-android-app-size-down

Comment: @DylanS I have already been through your posted link before and tried all the suggested options but still not being able to curb down the app size.

Comment: @Mainak Have you considered the possibility that your APK is as small as it can be? Have you looked at the APK to see what is actually taking up the space? If not, you can rename the APK to .zip (replace .apk with .zip), unzip the folder, and compare the sizes of the inner folders.